# GridView with multiple DataSources

Tags: vb.net

I have a grid view that will display columns from multiple data sources (3).
The data sources are stored procedures that contains a variety of columns not identical, How can i select the columns from these datasources and bind them to the Grid programtically (from code behind)???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create three separate datasets (one for each datasource that you'll be retreiving data from) and then merge them in code before binding.